# Can we install zabbix server and agents in 2 different networks?

Tags: http, proxy, zabbix, agents

We are planning to install zabbix in our production environment as we need to monitor around 10-12 servers. The key point here is we are planning to install the zabbix server on an external internet server while these 10 agents are on intranet.These agents have restricted accesses and cannot be accessed from outside.

I would like to know if it is possible to connect these agents with the server using http proxy.How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot use a HTTP proxy (at least without tunneling through it), your agents can connect to the server using active items in Zabbix. Note that this is configured on the item level.

Comment: Thanks @richlv for yr answer.but here I want to know how would it byepass the firewall in the above case if we use active agents?

Comment: It wouldn't bypass, the agents would still need a connection to the Zabbix server. In case of a severely restricted network you might use HTTP proxy tunneling, but I would advise against it - such a move might be viewed as circumvention of the security, provided by the firewall.